# Is it possible to call method after n minutes event if application will went to background

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, background

Is it possible to call method after n minutes even if application will go to background?
What i should use for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can fire a local notification after a set amount of time. But then you can only handle an event in case the user taps "View" on the dialog. Otherwise you can use one of the background modes (Location, Audio, VoIP) to continue running in the background. Then you have all the freedom you wish except that you probably won't get your app accepted in the app store unless you use your app for the purpose that you describe in your background mode.

I recently got an app rejected twice for polling every n minutes using location background mode (even though I was using the location!).

Good luck

Comment: Maybe i can write background task, that task sleep for 60 seconds and after do some actions.

Comment: I test this. I repeat perform actions every 1 seconds (use performSelector), and run background task. That task sleep fro 60 seconds.Then i press home button (app in background mode). While background task is performing, callbacks is raised after 1 seconds. And when background task stopped, callbacks stopped rased. What do you think about this?

Comment: If you press the home button and you won't the app to still respond you need to set one of the UIBackgroundModes in the applications plist. There is no "Timer" background mode. The closest would probably the audio mode. This would give you a frequent "hook".